# Using Query Result Count for Validation Rule (Even when empty)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, count, rules

I've made a custom validation rule `fiveMaxThemesChoice` which consists as the name may explain it in limiting a user (`Etudiant`) to a maximum choice of 5 `themes` in the app I'm building. This is the logic below with `EtudiantsChoixTheme` the Eloquent where I register the choices:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\EtudiantsChoixTheme;

class fiveMaxThemesChoice implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $choixEtudiants = EtudiantsChoixTheme::all();

            foreach ($choixEtudiants as $choixEtudiant) {
                  $IdEtudiantOccurences = count($choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id));
                if($IdEtudiantOccurences <= 5){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'You have already chosen a maximum of 5 themes.';
    }
}
```

When there is at least 1 record in the table, this works. The **issue** is that when the table get empty, the validation error message is returned even if there isn't any record yet in the table therefore not the maximum 5 (so `<= 5` is supposed to be right). Why is that not working tho?

I've tried with different syntax :

```
$IdEtudiantOccurences = count($choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id)->first());
```

```
$IdEtudiantOccurences = $choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id)->first()->count();
```

```
$IdEtudiantOccurences = $choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id)->count();
```

The same problem persists when the table is empty. Does anyone have an idea of what can be the problem here? Any help or suggestion is welcome

Comment: Probably because the foreach statement immediately skips its body, because it is ***empty***, so you are using neither of those explicit return statements (which are both within the foreach statement.  Make certain you have a default `return false;' before the end of the function body, and I'll bet it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\EtudiantsChoixTheme;

final class FiveMaxThemesChoice implements Rule
{
    private const MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_THEMES = 5;

    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        $idEtudiant = auth()->user()->id;
        $etudiantsQuery = EtudiantsChoixTheme::where('idEtudiant', $idEtudiant);

        return $etudiantsQuery->count() <= self::MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_THEMES;
    }

    public function message(): string
    {
        return 'You have already chosen a maximum of 5 themes.';
    }
}
```

Instead of fetching all (`EtudiantsChoixTheme::all();`) try doing the query directly and asking for the total after it (`EtudiantsChoixTheme::where(...)->count()`)

I took this idea from the official docu: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: Can you explain what OP got wrong? What this code does and why it works?

Comment: @Saly 3301 - See my comment on the original question for the "why"

Comment: @Chemaclass - Thanks.  I like your approach of using the count to determine the outcome, its elegant.

Comment: @Chemaclass Also use the `self::MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_THEMES` in  `message()` method.

Comment: @Chemaclass thank you for the answer. More logic and clean indeed. I've implemented it and I can get the verification done even if the table is empty. However it seems it stops now at 6 records actually instead of the 5 set. How that now

Comment: Then, try to change the condition to just `<` instead of `<=` @TedAaron

Comment: yes of course @Chemaclass, I was wondering why it did that. `<` is fine though thank you

Answer (score 0):

So here is your original body for `passes()`:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
        $choixEtudiants = EtudiantsChoixTheme::all();

        foreach ($choixEtudiants as $choixEtudiant) {

            $IdEtudiantOccurences = count($choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id));
            if($IdEtudiantOccurences <= 5){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    // So what value is returned here? PHP says NULL
}
```

For the foreach() loop to execute, it required that the collection be larger or equal to 1.  If it is empty, it won't be executed (hence neither of your explicit return statements being executed.)

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $choixEtudiants = EtudiantsChoixTheme::all();

    foreach ($choixEtudiants as $choixEtudiant) {

        $IdEtudiantOccurences = count($choixEtudiants->where('idEtudiant', auth()->user()->id));
        if($IdEtudiantOccurences <= 5){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

This version addresses that one lacking requirement.